# Or condition in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I use the operator "$or" in my query.

eg `find({ $or: [{ quantity: { $lt: 20 }}, { price: 10 }]})`

is there any way to tag records found by criterion "price: 10"?

Comment: Do you mean just `db.collection.find({ "price": 10 })`?

Comment: The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) can "inspect" each element and project a new field based on a logical match, therefore effectively "tagging". It does more than a simple "find" operation and can manipulate documents. Unless you actually need that projection to do "further" operations server side, then it is probably best to just inspect the values in your client code.

Answer (score 0):

No. The returned list is homogeneous, you will not know in that list if the entries were found because their quantity were less than 20, or their price was 10.

Just filter your array, or iterate:

```
var allMyEntries = find({ $or: [{ quantity: { $lt: 20 }}, { price: 10 }]});
for each entry in allMyEntries:
    if entry.price == 10
        //do whatever

    //do something else to all of them
```